# Which URL structure is recommended?

Tags: php, html, url, standards

I was wondering if I could get an opinion on the following structure. I am making a site where a company can register and then get their own page at the following URL

**company.site.com**

I am wondering to what address is it recommended that the administration is done for this company? I am thinking one of the following:

**company.site.com/admin** - Github style

- Unique to user
- Causes complications on login - what happens if they login at the wrong subdomain, are they forwarded, invalid login?

**admin.site.com** - Hotmail Style

- Makes login very simple, user sees what is relevant to them on this page, every user uses same URL
- Technically incorrect since admin is a sub page of company

Could anyone please give me their thoughts on how they would expect this to be structured.

Comment: I think that you should use the second option, because all the pages under the `company.site.com` domain should be manageable by the company (also the /admin page).

Comment: In that case do you mean the company.site.com/admin url?

Comment: I would go for admin.site.com, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pick a route that is technically easier to implement with your application architecture.

Second way is easier i think, because you still need to serve content that comes from user's domain, and you probably know what is user domain anyways.

First way - i'd say you have to make invalid login if user tries to login from wrong domain, otherwise this whole structure makes little sense, why would you basically create `/admin` at each domain separately, if you can still login to your panel from anywhere?

Also, have you considered site.com/admin, which is basically the second route but without weirdness of having reserved domain?

Comment: So have for example site.com/admin which can create a company page found at site.com/company perhaps? Thank you for the reply btw.

Comment: While creating a virtual directory is certainly easier than creating sub-domain from web interface, but latter seems better. And perhaps you should have two urls like `register` for page registration and `admin` for page administration.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first one.
As a user it`s more readable and easy to remember than the second one.

Answer (score 0):

company.site.com/admin is my preferred way.  Login and such would just need to be coded correctly.

My .02

Answer (score 0):

I am creating the exact same thing and I am using `company.site.com/admin` because in my application all users/members use the same dynamic files to administer their subdomain through sessions.